# Align superscript part after subscript part in equation

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equation-editor

I  would like to produce this in Microsoft Word using the equation tool:

[image]

However, entering `c_rms [space] ^2 [space]` produces this output instead:

[image]

How can I create an equation where the `^2` comes after the `_rms`, rather than being above it?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to enclose the variable in parentheses:

```
(c_rms)^2
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing temporarily, but it doesn't really produce the desired result because the parentheses show around the c_rms.